# MySQL, search for duplicates

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to find duplicates, so that they can be removed.

I have table called `categories`, which holds uid, qid, and value.

`uid` is unique ID for that table

`qid` is a question ID

`value` is tag for that qid

as such, we can have many rows per qid, but each qid should have unique values.

For example:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM categories WHERE qid=6869;

+-------+------+-----------+
| uid   | qid  | value     |
+-------+------+-----------+
| 19838 | 6869 | Sport     |
| 19839 | 6869 | Football  |
| 19840 | 6869 | Sport     |
| 19841 | 6869 | Athletics |
+-------+------+-----------+
```

As you can see, it has two `Sport`. We have over 8 000 qids in there, each with 3-8 tags... I really don't want to go through each qid manually.

So at the very least, I'd love to get a list of `qid`'s with this issue, and at best, to remove all duplicates.

What I've tried:

```
SELECT count(value) AS cnt FROM categories GROUP BY value HAVING cnt>1;
```

which gave me a table with a lot of numbers, but I couldn't make it to print out more than just that, since I got this error:

```
mysql> SELECT *, count(value) AS cnt FROM categories GROUP BY value HAVING cnt>1;
ERROR 1055 (42000): Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'quizmastershop.categories.uid' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by
```

Also, it's not quite what I need, since it gives me only a count of each value...

Any ideas?

Cheers

EDIT: Version data

```
mysql> SELECT VERSION();
+-------------------------+
| VERSION()               |
+-------------------------+
| 5.7.21-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 |
+-------------------------+
```

EDIT 2: I removed `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` from sql_mode string. My string above which produced error is still not providing me with anything useful

EDIT 3: Tried Erics code, and this is the output which is exactly what I needed :-)

```
+-------+------+-------------------+
| uid   | qid  | value             |
+-------+------+-------------------+
|   470 |  170 | Children's        |
|   472 |  170 | Children's        |
|   570 |  204 | Geography         |
|   572 |  204 | Geography         |
|   575 |  205 | Geography         |
|   577 |  205 | Geography         |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the code below.  Basically the inner query grab records that have multiple entries.  The outer query join it back to categories table to get the uid.

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.uid, c.qid, c.value
FROM categories c
JOIN (
    SELECT qid, value, COUNT(*)
    FROM categories
    GROUP BY qid, value
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) a ON a.qid = c.qid AND a.value = c.value
```

Comment: there is slight typo in the outer SELECT. should be qid rather than quid :-) I'm getting this error: `ERROR 1052 (23000): Column 'qid' in field list is ambiguous`

Comment: @RobertMoritz Both table `c` and `a` has same column names (`qid` and `uid`), so you need to qualify them with table name.

Comment: you are amazing. It works perfectly :-) Edit 3 shows the output of your code

Answer (score 2):

```
Select * from categories where value in (SELECT value  FROM categories GROUP BY value HAVING count(value)>1)
```

Comment: ```mysql> Select * from categories where uid in (SELECT uid FROM categories GROUP BY value HAVING count(value)>1);```
  
`ERROR 1055 (42000): Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'quizmastershop.categories.uid' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by`

Comment: I have no problem with changing the settings, however what are the implications?

Comment: @soft87 You should refrain from just "code dropping" -- And explain what the SQL statement is actually doing.  Providing an answer, and enlightening someone as to *why* the answer works (or doesn't) are two separate things.